# Как сделать чтобы радиоботтоны пропадали после выбора?

Tags: javascript, css, input

Как сделать, чтобы после выбора переключателя в HTML (радиокнопки) (кнопка 1 или кнопка 2) переключатели пропадали?

Comment: постарайтесь давать более развернутые вопросы, желательно с примерами и попытками решения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо что-то около того)

```js
let mama = document.querySelectorAll('.mama');

for( let i = 0; i < mama.length; i++ ){
  let radio = mama[i].querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
  for( let gaga = 0; gaga < radio.length; gaga++ ){
    radio[gaga].name = "googoo" + i;
    
    radio[gaga].addEventListener('change', function(){
      for( let u = 0; u < radio.length; u++ ){
        if( u == gaga ){
          this.classList.add('hidden'); 
          this.parentNode.classList.add('chosen');          
          continue; 
        }
        radio[u].parentNode.classList.add('hidden');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.mama label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 180px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #fcc;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.mama label:hover { background-color: #d7a; color: black; }

.mama .chosen {
  color: white;
  background-color: #913;
}

.mama .hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="mama">
  <label><input type="radio"> <span>Мишки</span></label>
  <label><input type="radio"> <span>Мимимишки</span></label>
</div>

<div class="mama">
  <label><input type="radio"> <span>Слон</span></label>
  <label><input type="radio"> <span>Кит</span></label>
</div>

<div class="mama">
  <label><input type="radio"> <span>Бабаски</span></label>
  <label><input type="radio"> <span>От зайца</span></label>
  <label><input type="radio"> <span>С первого раза</span></label>
</div>
```

Вопросы?)

Если вообще ничего из этого не понятно, вам сюда → http://learn.javascript.ru/

Comment: Не получилось (

Comment: @Ivan Так вы перепутали все теги... на JsFiddle удобнее писать такой код, сразу высвечивает ошибки. Но если бы ошибок и не было - у вас скрипт стоял вверху, а браузер читает весь код сверху вниз. Т.е. не будет работать, если запрашивает HTML-элемент, который еще не загружен. Скрипт переносим в конец и работает →  https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/wkgs30xc/ но код именно под эту разметку. Если поставить радио внутри label, не придется каждый раз вручную заполнять им id - он и так будет переключать. А name - заполняется автоматически, в самом скрипте (`radio[gaga].name`) тоже можно вручную не писать.

Comment: вы бы не могли подсказать как div вставить в input required?

Comment: div в input ? А для чего?)

Comment: @Ivan Я не до конца разобрался в вашей форме. Но упрощенный вариант "не отправлять, пока не подтвердили", выглядит так → https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/u6xbdkme/

Comment: а это можно другими способами сделать?